# How to align specific columns, for several lines simultaneously?

Tags: align, column

Consider i want to make something like this

```
row one goes like this
row two goes like this
woops like this
woops like what happend now
```

and i want the `like` to be aligned in all sentences, something like this:

```
row one goes like this
row two goes like this
woops        like this
woops        like what happend now
```

Now imagine i want to do this for 100+ lines, is there a way to indent my lines effective without having to go through every line?

I have tried `M-i`, which is perfect for 1 row, but i can't figure out the vertical aligning part,

Comment: Try `M-x align-regexp`. Mark region, input `M-x align-regexp`, press RETURN, and input `like` as alignment regexp.

Comment: @Tobias Works as a charm, add this as an answer and i will accept it. (Also if you could add an explanation how to change the length of the indent itself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `like` <kbd>RET</kbd>.
Thereby `like` stands for the regexp identifying the part of the line that should be aligned.

Note that the variable `align-to-tab-stop` influences the alignment. If it is set to `indent-tabs-mode` tabs are inserted for alignment.
Set it to `nil` if you want spaces instead.

There is also the "expert mode" of `align-regexp` where you can specify the regexp group that is expanded for alignment, the alignment size, and whether you want rather to justify the text instead of alignment.

The key sequence for the expert mode is <kbd>C-u M-x</kbd> `align-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> ...